# Find all cycles based on label of edge in a disconnected labeled Un-directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

1.The condition for a cycle to be valid in this graph is such that the edges forming a cycle should have at least one label common between all of them.
2. Loops are not considered as cycles.
3. Graph may have lots of disconnected components  .

Consider the following graph

[image]

The valid cycles are
       1. C,D,E(since T3 is common among them).
       2. F,G,H (T4 is common among them).

The invalid cycles are
         1. A (loops are not considered as cycles)
         2. A,B,C (As no common labels are found).

The goal is to find those valid cycles and store the vertices along with common labels that formed the cycle separately(may be in a hash table with vertices of cycle as key and common labels as values).

what will be the best cycle detection algorithm that can be applied to this kind of problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @smith. I found out that dfs can work but I was looking if there are any other better way of doing this by taking the advantage of edge label constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution that I can think is separate those graph based on the edge label.

For example you have this graph:

```
A --T1-- B
B --T2,T1-- C
C --T3,T1-- A
```

As there are three labels, create three graphs based on the edge.

```
T1:
A --T1-- B
B --T1-- C
C --T1-- A

T2:
B --T2-- C

T3:
C --T3-- A
```

After that you can do [Depth First Search (DFS) algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-undirected-graph/) to find the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the algorithm described in [this article about finding all cycles in an undirected graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-the-cycles-in-an-undirected-graph/).

However, the small modification needed is that you must run the algorithm described `k` iterations where `k` is the number of distinct labels. Additionally, each time you run the algorithm, only consider edges with the label `T_i`.

The running time with the modification is `O(k(M + N))`. Note that this side-steps the need to "create" `k` separate graphs as described by malioboro.